# Jest custom filename patterns

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm trying to pass a custom file pattern to `jest` cli but I'm not 100% as to why it's returning no found matches?

```
yarn jest index.integration.js
```

Comment: and when you try yarn jest integration ?

Comment: Thanks, the one thing I didn't try is without the .js